# How can I get android full screen on application level?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, fullscreen

I managed to get full screen on activity level. But I can't on application level.

When I move android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" from activity to application part, then red X appears on the left side of my Manifest page.

What shall I do? Please help me out.

Comment: The 'application' doesn't have a 'screen' - it's invisible and exists as a background framework for all other components. You'll have to set it on every `Activity`. Either that or use a single `Activity` with `Fragments`.

Comment: You mean I can not get fullscreen on application level? What do you think of Fouad Wahabi's coding on application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well like this :

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

can you set the error shown ?

Comment: Thanks for your mention. I applied your solution to my manifest, but it is still what it was.  With someone's help, I can get fullscreen on activity level. He says that " Replace ActionBarActivity with FragmentActivity in the MainActivity.java" It works only on activity level. But I want every page in my app. Anyway to get there?

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        >

Comment: aah  just delete android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  and  it will works

Comment: I'll try, and then let you know. Thanks

Comment: @민현식 :) please can you upvote and set my answer as right answer ?

Comment: To Fouad Wahabi, I try to upvote for you, the box reads "Vote up requires 15 reputaions" what does it mean? And How can I set your answer as right answer? Sorry I am new here.

Comment: @민현식 thanks answer is picked , and for upvoting you have to get more than 15 reputations : reputations is like score for example when somone upvote for your question or for your response you gonne get 2+ reputations and when somone pick your answer as right answer you gonne get 15+ reptutations , and welcome to StackOverFlow comunnity :)